# awesome_print integration with pry - getting dependencies.rb:247:in `require' error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-console, pry

I am trying to use awesome_print (1.2.0) with pry. Both gem awesome_print (1.2.0) and Pry version 0.10.1 is installed on Ruby 2.1.2.

Currently i am able to use run pry while running rails console, however i am not able to make awesome_print work with pry.

Currently i am working on mac and as per the instruction in https://github.com/michaeldv/awesome_print, i need to create ~/.pryrc with the following command:

```
require "awesome_print"
AwesomePrint.pry!
```

However, while running rails console i am getting following error: 
[image]

Comment: `bundle show awesome_print` what it returns?

Comment: @RajarshiDas ,thank you for getting me into the right direction, it was a easy fix. 

bundle show awesome_print gave: "Could not find gem 'awesome_print' ". I just had to add awesome_print gem and bundle install. Now its working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Please do it first

`bundle show awesome_print`

And if you do not get any error then it is showing the path of that gem

else

in Gemfile

```
gem  'awesome_print'
```

and

`bundle install`

Then

`bundle exec rails c`

And in console you get

```
  `require "awesome_print"`
```

it will return `true`